# iOS - Can users access App Bundle Contents (specifically the Bundle Resources)

Tags: ios, file, resources, filesystems, bundle

I'm relatively new to iOS development. My question is quite simple but there seems to be a lot of un-complete answers out there.

For example, I have a few pictures that are used in my app and I don't want the users to have access to these pictures at all (due to copyright). I've included these into the "Bundle Resources" along with the "Image.cxassets" and other .xib files.

Will the user ever be able to access the pictures? (I understand that the user can't access the Library folder but it seems to be a pain to copy the pictures into the Library folder at app first launch.)

thanks ahead for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what exactly you're asking, but for users to access your app bundle contents the file sharing for iTunes option should be set in .plist. See in the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30)

Although you may put dot before file ".image.jpg" to make it hidden but it sounds like temporary solution.